# Content Management System in Rails 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am using rails 3. When implementing CMS, the body was supposed to displays the following:

```
<h1>Welcome to our home page</h1>.
```

but display the text with its tags.
In my `views/viewer/show.html`, I placed the following code: `<%= @page.body %>`.

What can I do so solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails does this to protect you from [XSS attacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#cross-site-scripting-xss). To prevent the tags from showing literally, you can use [`html_safe`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-html_safe):

```
<%= @page.body.html_safe %>
```

Only use `html_safe` if you understand the consequences! You maybe opening up your application to XSS attacks if you don't.

Comment: @user2545685, please keep in mind Mischas remarks about XSS attacks. this has to be taken seriously

Comment: Yes I do understand. I'm just testing the commands. Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

It's confusing what you are trying to achieve.
If all you want to show is a line in that page, then:

In your app/controllers/viewer_controller do:

```
@message = "Welcome to our home page"
```

In you view app/views/viewer/show.html do:

```
</html>
  <body>
    <%= @message%>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem seems to be that HTML is not rendered as HTML. Instead the tags are displayed literally in the browser.

Comment: ah ok. i get it. stackoverflow parsed away the h1 tags in the question.